# Search and replace same visual region

Tags: vim

This comes up more than expected. Suppose I want to do multiple search and replaces in the same visual region. The current steps I use to do this is:

- `V` to select the lines
- `:'<,'>s/classes/teachers/g`
- `V` to select the same lines again
- `:'<,'>s/class/teacher/g`

Is there a shortcut where I don't need to select the same visual region twice?

Comment: If the selected area is the same, the marks `'<` and `'>` don't change (they are not erased by the `:s` command), so you should be able to do your substitutions one after another without having to reselect the lines, don't you?

Comment: For the particular problem described above see also the [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you selected single line, for `:s` command, the range `'<,'>` is always the single line, that is, you can save this range, just `:s/foo/bar/g`.
- If you have multiple lines visual selected, you can always re-select them by pressing `gv` in normal mode
- actually you can concatenate two `:s` commands, do the two substitutions in one shot:`:'<,'>s/classes/teachers/g|'<,'>s/class/teacher/g`

Answer (score 2):

With gv you should be able to reselect the previous selection

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#gv